# Open old app this message told me problem

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Open old app this message told me problem.

> Could not find method taskclean() for arguments [{type=class
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.Delete},
>   build_2ep35kdoesf1fdcr2my3t2kqi$_run_closure2@1deb1fad] on root
>   project 'playmusicexporter-develop' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> taskclean(type:Delete) {
>   deleterootProject.buildDir
> }
> ```

The section above is erroneous. You have missed some spaces in between. Change it like  this:

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Update:**

For your updated 2nd problem, still missing space is a problem. It should be like:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Comment: and picture no 2